# Proxy trap that applies to all objects?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, es6-proxy

I want to write a Proxy trap which applies to all objects. I'm trying to modify the behaviour of all JS objects using the `set` trap, by replacing a specific value with a predefined getter/setter pair.

```js
// This
const myObj = {
  foo: getterSetter
}

// Is the same as this
const myObj = {
  get foo() { ... }
  set foo(v) { ... }
```

I've tried:

- Redefining `Object.prototype.constructor` to return a Proxy

  ```js
  Object.prototype.constructor = function() {
    return new Proxy( ... )
  }
  ```
- Setting `Object.prototype` to a Proxy

  ```js
  Object.prototype = new Proxy( ... )
  ```

Neither correctly implements the Proxy trap behaviour on all objects.

Is there a way in which this can be done?

Non Proxy solutions are also welcome.

Comment: This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @VLAZ I was expecting someone to ask. I'm trying to create a compact syntax for inserting a predefined getter/setter pair into an object (literal?).

Comment: That is *vastly* different to saying "all objects" which would include modification arrays, as well as custom classes, DOM elements, and everything else.

Comment: @ VLAZ It should be able to be assigned using `=` as well, so yes, all objects.

Comment: You lost me again.

Comment: @VLAZ For example: `const myObject = { foo: getterSetter }` will call `Object.defineProperty` and create a getter and setter on the property `foo`. That's my goal.

Comment: And also `new MyPerson()`?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, all objects. `const person = new MyPerson(); person.foo = getterSetter` and ditto.

Comment: Note that rather than waiting until someone to ask and then explaining in comments, you can just explain *in the question*. Then people don't have to write the comment, you don't have to write the comments, and there's a lot less wasted time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I didn't think explaining *why* I needed this would be necessary to put in the question, and I thought I already explained the question clearly enough. I was wrong on both fronts.